# Wired connection activated but no wire plugged in?

Tags: networking, ethernet

Something weird happened to my computer just now.

I use Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and was browsing the internet. Suddenly I see my wifi trying to connect. Wondering If I had disconnected from my rooter I check it and I see that I am connecting_?_connected to "Wired Connection 1" ?!

I disconnected from it and now my computer is normally connected to my rooter. If I go on my to Edit Connections > Network Connections I see under Ethernet tab a connection named "Wired Connection 1". This is the only Ethernet Connection available and I ve never plugged an ethernet cable at my laptop after I formatted and Installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 less than a month ago.

The device listed is ens5 (20:CF:30:64:97:34).
I disabled the options to automatically connect to it.

On two USB ports I have connected an mouse and my Android phone although they shouldn't matter for an Ethernet connection (given it's a different port).

How do I investigate this?

P.S. In case this is relevant I have used [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1409032/comments/29) fix to not have gvfsd-smb-browse get stuck at 100% CPU.

update:

By going at [this site](http://wintelguy.com/index.pl) I found that this MAC address partially corresponds to ASUSTek COMPUTER INC. which is my laptop's manufacturer. (My laptop is an Asus N61Jq.)  Is it possible that the OS fumbled somehow? Can I find any logs about it?

This, coupled with some googling, prompted me to run `ifconfig` from where I get:

```
ens5      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:cf:30:64:97:34  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:860 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:860 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:89183 (89.1 KB)  TX bytes:89183 (89.1 KB)

wls1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5d:60:3a:b8:1c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::13e2:45b8:cf50:5466/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd20:a680:5e21:2300:e4fb:fd03:ba5c:c539/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fd20:a680:5e21:2300:6636:ad0a:1428:6a64/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:41594 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27704 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:45620375 (45.6 MB)  TX bytes:4326829 (4.3 MB)
```

The third is my rooter's wifi connection (is it a bad idea if I have so much info from it posted?). The other two I am not sure what they are. But the first one looks suspiciously similar to the Wired Connection 1 that tried to autostart. Is it that case? And Why, How?!?